# How to streaming from an .avi container without encoding it in H264 or H265

Tags: stream, streaming, codec, azure-media-services, avi

I would like to stream a .avi container and not use any codec in the encoding process, that is, I do not want it to encode in H264 or H265, just upload the video and do not encode it, I am using the Azure SDK media services in .NET.
The presets that azure media services has for example in their sdk, they all use h264 or h265 to encode and return an mp4, I just want to upload .avi and see if it is possible that it does not apply any compression and then download the .avi
Thanks!

Comment: What is inside the AVI?  AVI is just a container file format - and it contains either an audio codec or a video codec of some type.  You need to know what is in it first before you can consider any solutions that do not require transcoding.  Reason is - the device you want to play back on may not have the codec at all. 
Also, AVI is not a streaming container format.  At best, you can download it and hope someone has the codecs that are in it.

Comment: @johndeu the .avi container contains a sequence of bits (we can say images in rgb24 pixel format) and is not encoded with any codec, that is, it is rawvideo. And indeed once I download the chunk (video in a resolution) when I stream, I myself know how to rebuild it ... but the problem is that Azure Media Services applies h264 to me in the streaming process and that's what I don't want to do...

Comment: I simply want to use the preset that Azure media services uses but that when I use h264 to encode I do it without loss, that is, crf 0

Comment: I'm very confused on what the use case is that you are trying to get to.  Can you explain a lot more?  Are you ok with transcoding now?  Are you trying to steam in HLS or DASH format to a device/player that supports it?  Are you planning on building your own player with a custom streaming protocol?  Are you wanting to download the file progressively and play it back?  Is this streaming at scale, or one to few?  
Check this - https://howvideo.works/

Comment: I want to stream an mp4 that I have built, and the information it has is correct, I do not want more bytes to be lost than it has, so when applying the sdk of azure media services, which uses h264 it is compressing me and I am losing bytes that I won't know how to rebuild later (I can't give many details of what the video contains, it's something confidential of the project I'm working on), my question is, can you use the azure media services SDK, where when coding do it with crf = 0, that is, encode without loss ???

Comment: Let me check on the CRF settings for you. I know that we had a story to add in CRF support in the standard encoder a while back, but I don't see it in the SDK or REST API currently.

Comment: Stone, the SDK is out for .NET that has the CRF support now. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer here.  It looks like you were wanting to do a lossless, or near lossless encoding pass using CRF (constant rate factor encoding).  There is currently no support for setting CRF encoding in the standard encoder in AMS, but there is work going on to add CRF encoding settings to the SDK in the near future.

For now, you are limited to the settings available in the Transform preset in the H264 or H265 Layers.
You can see all of the available encoding settings most easily in the REST API

https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/mediaservices/resource-manager/Microsoft.Media/stable/2021-06-01/Encoding.json

Or if you look at the Transform object in your favorite SDK. Look at the H264Video and H264 Layer classes in the model, as well as the H265 equivalent ones for settings you can control in your code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.h264video?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.h264layer?view=azure-dotnet

UPDATE: SDK for .NET is available now with Exposed RateControlMode for H264 encoding, enabling 2 new ratecontrol modes - CBR (Constant Bit Rate) and CRF (Constant Rate Factor).
See- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your answer, then we will have to wait for the new configurations to be released with the azure .net sdk. Thanks!

Comment: SDK is out now for .NET  with CRF support - other SDKs should be up very soon. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media

"Exposed RateControlMode for H264 encoding, enabling 2 new ratecontrol modes - CBR (Constant Bit Rate) and CRF (Constant Rate Factor)."